# Defining a macro that does nothing

Tags: defmacro

I am defining a macro that accepts any number of arguments that actually do nothing.  From a previous discussion, it was pointed out to me that a macro does not evaluate its arguments, which is beneficial to me because I could pass anything, with Emacs Lisp not trying to evaluate things that are ignored anyway.

This is the first time I delve into macros.  Can one loop through the arguments with `dolist` when using `&rest args` ?

```
(defmacro ndkat (&rest _args)
  "No matter how many arguments are passed, no actions will be
performed.  Returns 'nil'."

  nil)
```

Comment: Yes, the macro code can loop through the unevaluated elements in the list bound to your `&rest` argument, `_args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
(defmacro ndkat (&rest _args))
```

Then in *scratch* buffer `(ndkat (message "hello" "world") 123)` with `C-x C-e` after the last `)` does nothing.

Comment: There is no need to return `nil` ?

Comment: I believe if you have docstring then `nil` is needed, otherwise docstring is returned.